# How to check if CSF firewall is running

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, csf

My ex-system admin installed CSF on a server witout Admin panel. I can see CSF installed but I am not sure if its currently running or not. I dont want to try to start / stop it.

I realized there is no PID file concept in CSF and I am finding it hard to know if the server is currently running CSF or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Firewall information" or "Check server security" in CSF.

Or run in shell(if firewall run output contain many rules)

```
sudo iptables -nv -L
```

Comment: if he has only rules in say nat table you wont see antything with that  -nv -L

Comment: @HrvojeŠpoljar CSF don't support nat table. CSF control only filter table.

Comment: heh well who knows what may or may not be there, OP mentions "ex-admin" you never know what someone left before you...

Comment: I tried using this command and got some enteries. How to be sure that CSF is running and the rules were not added manually

Comment: Block IP from CSF, then `iptables -nv -L|grep BLOCKIP`

Answer (score 1):

run

`iptables-save`

command and check out what output is.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@vps ~/ # csf -l
csf and lfd have been disabled, use 'csf -e' to enable
root@vps ~/ # csf -e |head
DROP  tcp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  tcp dpt:67
DROP  udp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  udp dpt:67
DROP  tcp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  tcp dpt:68
DROP  udp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  udp dpt:68
DROP  tcp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  tcp dpt:111
DROP  udp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  udp dpt:111
DROP  tcp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  tcp dpt:113
DROP  udp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  udp dpt:113
DROP  tcp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  tcp dpts:135:139
DROP  udp opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0  udp dpts:135:139
```

I'm using "head" because I have VERBOSE enabled

```
 258 # Enable verbose output of iptables commands
 259 VERBOSE = "1"
```

If you change it to 0, you will get:

```
root@vps ~/ # csf -e
Starting lfd:[  OK  ]
csf and lfd have been enabled
root@vps ~/ #
```

Comment: Shit.. 2 years old ... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If CSF and LFD are already enabled, then running the following command

```
sudo csf -e
```

will output

```
csf and lfd are not disabled!
```

In addition you can try the following:

```
sudo service csf status
```